# Using the mTurk Worker and Requester Sandbox

Tags: mturk

How do you use the worker sandbox to preview your HIT? As someone without any programming experience, the instructions mTurk gave aren't very clear. I have both an mTurk requester sandbox and worker sandbox, but don't know how to proceed from here. I basically want to see what my HIT would look like to a worker (without publishing it yet). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To see what your HIT would look like you first need to create a HIT using your Requester Account. Afterwards you can click on "Publish Batch", follow the process and click on "Publish" - **this will only publish your HIT to the Sandbox!** (As you can read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/mturk-use-sandbox.html).) After a few seconds you can find your own HIT in the worker sandbox by searching for your name, keywords or the description of your HIT.